# Determine whether an account type is business or enterprise?

Tags: box-api

I know how to determine if account type is personal or not personal by `max_upload_size` using v2 API:

https://api.box.com/2.0/users/me

or add extra fields `can_see_managed_users` or `is_exempt_from_device_limits`, then check the response.

But I assume the business account has the storage limitation, which means the response of `is_exempt_from_device_limits` should be false for business account. So I created a business account and tested on it. The result is true instead.

So is there any api or flags which can be used to determine the difference?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that you can determine that an account is a business or enterprise account by the max_upload_size setting.  You've also discovered an administrative feature, that the admins can set on their enterprise account.   They can decide if their users are allowed to have multiple devices of the same kind that are allowed to login.

There isn't a specific API at the moment to determine what type of account the user has.   We're contemplating it, but for now, the max_upload_size is probably the best way to gauge.   Keep in mind that Box keeps changing that limit.  We have been slowly raising that limit on various types of accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Box user API now returns an enterprise object. I believe we can use this to determine if it is a business account or enterprise account like this:

```
"enterprise": {
    "type": "enterprise",
    "id": "17077211",
    "name": "seanrose enterprise"
}
```